# Making `matplotlib.pyplot.plot()` work with `PeriodIndex

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a DataFrame (`df`) that has a PeriodIndex and corresponding column of integers (`OrderQuantity`). (Think of this as data about quantities sold in a day for a particular product). In order to do some simple visualization of this data using `matplotlib.pyplot.plot()`, I am having to convert the PeriodIndex into Timestamp, otherwise the `plot()` method throws an error `TypeError: Axis must have`freq`set to convert to Periods`. It appears MatPlotLib tries to convert the PeriodIndex into  Periods, without realizing that it already has Periods.

So, for now, the following works:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
plt.plot(df.index.to_timestamp(), df.OrderQuantity) // produces a valid plot
```

I am wondering if there is a better way of plotting Periods without having to convert to a Timestamp, which pyplot will internally convert back to a Periods before generating the graph.

Comment: `df.OrderQuantity.plot()`?

Comment: @Goyo, thank you for your suggestion. `df.OrderQuantity.plot()` is not an option because I am trying to have multiple dataframes on the same graph (test and training data), and some resampling is also needed since the number of data points is really large. The question is really about using PeriodIndex in `plt.plot()`, not so much about different ways to generate a plot from a series.

Comment: I don't think there is a convenient way to use the `PeriodIndex` as is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pandas.DataFrame.plot()` has a keyword argument `ax` to explicitly specify which Axes to plot on, so you can create a Figure based on two (or more) DataFrames. For example,

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(42)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randint(5, 20, size=7), columns=['foo'],
    index=pd.period_range('2019-05-30', periods=7, freq='D')
)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randint(15, 40, size=7), columns=['bar'],
    index=pd.period_range('2019-05-30', periods=7, freq='D')
)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df1.plot(ax=ax)
df2.plot(ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

will produce the following plot.

[image: output image]